# If $X_n$ is a bounded sequence of random vars $X_n \overset{\mathbb{P}}{\rightarrow} 0 \Rightarrow \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}|X_n| = 0$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Currently working on the following problem: Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random varibales and $C$ a constant with $\mathbb{P}[|X_n| > M] = 0$  for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $X_n \overset{\mathbb{P}}{\rightarrow} 0 \Rightarrow \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}|X_n| = 0$.

I struggle to formulate the proof because of the general nature of $X_n$, however I think I have an intuition why this is true: Intuitively convergence in probability does not care about the values of $X_n$ as long as the set of points where they significantly deviate from $0$ is sufficient small in the limit. The convergence in expectation however also accounts for the values of the random variable, so if the value increases faster than the probability shrinks on a given set the resulting sequence does not converge to zero. The constant $C$ prevents precisely that the value dominates the probability.

Any help to formulate this rigorously?

Answer (score 1):

For any $\epsilon > 0$,
$$E|X_n| = \int_{|X_n|\leq\epsilon} |X_n|dP + \int_{|X_n|> \epsilon} |X_n|dP$$

$$\leq \epsilon + P\{|X_n|> \epsilon\} M.$$

Now what can you conclude from $X_n \to 0$ in probability?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\mathbb E[\vert X_n\vert]=\mathbb E[\vert X_n\vert1_{\{\vert X_n\vert\ge\varepsilon\}}]+\mathbb E[\vert X_n\vert1_{\{\vert X_n\vert<\varepsilon\}}]\le M\mathbb P(\vert X_n\vert\ge\varepsilon)+\varepsilon\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}\varepsilon
$$
for $\varepsilon>0$ arbitrarily small.